# Using multiple image galleries inside Twitter Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I have created 3 image galleries based on [SlidesJS](http://beta.slidesjs.com/) and placed them inside [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs).

You can see the [demo](http://www.shanycosmetics.com.php54-1.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=8) here.

As you can see, the galleries are correctly populated and placed inside the tabs; however, the images for the second and third galleries are not displayed.

I'm guessing this might be something with the content of the tabs being hidden and conflicting with the gallery css?

Do you have any solution?

**Answer:**

Based on the suggestion below, I ended up using it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slides0').slidesjs({ width: 918, height: 200, navigation: false });
    $("#gallery-tab a").each(function( index ) {
        $(this).on('shown', function(){
            $('#slides' + index).slidesjs({ width: 918, height: 200, navigation: false });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common problem with most tab scenarios is that you're initializing your galleries when the tabs are hidden, and therefore the plugin cannot calculate sizes and perform other actions on tab child elements which aren't visible.

You can 1) initialize the gallery plugin on tab select, or 2) use something like `{position: absolute; left: -999em;}` instead of `{display: none}` to hide tabs.

UPDATE: Based on your comment, this should work...

```
$('#gallery-tab a:first[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function () {
   $('#slides0').slidesjs({ width: 918, height: 200, navigation: false });
})
```

Comment: I tried both your solutions, but still couldn't get the images to appear. I did (and repeated for each link respectively): 
$('#gallery-tab a:first').click(function (e) {
  
   $('#slides0').slidesjs({
  width: 918,
  height: 200,
  navigation: false
 });
})

Comment: Normally you'd run that as a tab plugin callback, not a separate click function.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I updated my post to reflect the answer. Do you know if it'd be possible to automate this? For example if I add another gallery, I don't wanna go to the js and add another line.

Comment: Sure, you can use jQuery to find elements relative to the tab. You don't need to use hard-coded IDs. You'd put a class on your slide instance and instantiate that class inside the tab being clicked.